# create a UIModalPresentationFormSheet

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to create a user guide for my app to show only once. How can I create a simple UIModalPresentationFormSheet with some text in it?

EDIT:

```
UIViewController *newItemViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View.xib" bundle:nil];
newItemViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:newItemViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store value in NSUserDeafualts. So in your main UIViewController in viewDidAppear :

```
 #define SHOULD_SHOW_KEY @"shouldShowKey"
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
//Get user defaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//if there is no object for SHOULD_SHOW_KEY present modal contoroler
if (![defaults objectForKey:SHOULD_SHOW_KEY]) {
    //Set object for key and synchronize defaults
    [defaults setObject:SHOULD_SHOW_KEY forKey:SHOULD_SHOW_KEY];
    [defaults synchronize];
    //Present any custom modal controller
    UIViewController *yourModalVC=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myModalVC"];
    [self presentModalViewController:yourModalVC animated:YES];
}
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: but how can I actually load it (see the edit, I tried that code)

Comment: 5.1 to 6.0. I use storyboards

Comment: you can use [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myModalVC"]; Need to set identifier(Storyboard ID) in your storyboard graphical view